# Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices->Publish fails when database name contains single quotes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to publish/create a database using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices->Publish(..) method as follows..

### My C# code:

```
using (DacPackage dacpac = DacPackage.Load(dacpacStream, DacSchemaModelStorageType.Memory, FileAccess.Read))
{                    
    dacOptions.BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges = true;
    var result = dacServiceInstance.Publish(dacpac, databaseName, new PublishOptions { CancelToken = packageDeplyCancellationToken.Token, DeployOptions = dacOptions, GenerateDeploymentReport = true });
    dacServiceInstance.Register(databaseName, "Engage", dacpac.Version);
}
```

My databaseName variable contains a db name with single quotes like
 "Dileep's Archive". In this case the Publish method fails to create the database and throws the following error. 
But it works if i manually try to create database with single quotes from SQL Mangement studio.

Can any one suggest what should be done to be able to create database with Single quotes.

I have tried by escaping the single quotes, by giving another like "Dileep''Archive" but now it creates the database with 2 single quotes..

### Error:

> Could not deploy package. Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near
>   'Dileep's Archive'. Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The
>   executed script:

```
IF (DB_ID(N'$(DatabaseName)') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @rc AS INT, @fn AS NVARCHAR (4000), @dir AS NVARCHAR (4000);
        EXECUTE @rc = [master].[dbo].[xp_instance_regread] N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'BackupDirectory', @dir OUTPUT, 'no_output';
        IF (@rc = 0)
            SELECT @dir = @dir + N'\';
        IF (@dir IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE @rc = [master].[dbo].[xp_instance_regread] N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', @dir OUTPUT, 'no_output';
                IF (@rc = 0)
                    SELECT @dir = @dir + N'\';
            END
        IF (@dir IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE @rc = [master].[dbo].[xp_instance_regread] N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup', N'SQLDataRoot', @dir OUTPUT, 'no_output';
                IF (@rc = 0)
                    SELECT @dir = @dir + N'\Backup\';
            END
        IF
```

Comment: Why do you WANT to create a database with a space and single quote? Honestly, don't... When creating objects in SQL Server, don't use special Characters, or white space, or start the object's name with a numeric. Object names **should** consist of the characters 0-9, A-Z and a-z. If you really want to represent a whitespace, use an underscore (_). Using special characters in database names just makes things difficult. Say, for example, you create a database called `Integers [10]` you'd have to write `USE [Integers [[10]]];`  Just to access it. It's messy. Strip it down to `DileepsArchive`.

Comment: Our customers are used to single quotes while creating databases..like "Dan's Archive" , "Maxim's Archive" etc :) , hence this requirement...so as per you comment, we may need to educate not to use quotes or any other special characters..

Comment: If you do have to use special characters, you'll have to quote your object names. As I said above, the quote characters for SQL Server objects are brackets (`[ ]`). If, however, you include a bracket in the name of the object, then you need to double them up.

Comment: Thanks..will check and let you know..

Comment: In the debug mode, i modified by databaseName variable from "Dileep'sArchive" to "[Dileep'sArchive]" . The Publish method still throws error..
This is the line throwing error..
 dacServiceInstance.Publish(dacpac, databaseName, new PublishOptions { CancelToken = packageDeplyCancellationToken.Token, DeployOptions = dacOptions, GenerateDeploymentReport = true });